# Performing a costly unpadding operation

Tags: iphone, ios

Filter effects show some warning  Performing a costly unpadding operation!  also some memory leak after apply on image?

my code is :-

```
        CIImage *imagee = [Filter outputImage];
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage: 
                              imagee fromRect: imagee.extent];
        UIImage *resultUIImage = [[UIImage alloc ]initWithCGImage: cgImage];
        image=resultUIImage; 
        CGImageRelease(cgImage);
        cgImage=nil;
        SaveImage=image;
        [resultUIImage release];
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172838/performing-a-costly-unpadding-operation-what-is-it-and-how-to-fix-it. The console warning definitely didn't have to do with releasing the context in my case.

Comment: What is the precise message, and what line is it pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't releasing your CIImage, which is most likely where that leak is coming from (Cocoa Memory Semantics require that class methods return objects with a +0 retain count so they must be retained by the caller).  At the same time, you are performing an expensive filtering of the image.  You see, images may be padded with a couple extra bytes to make sure that their lines end in a 2^nth byte.  But in order to load the filter, iOS has to unpad the image, which involves going in and iterating through its bytes to remove padding, which takes a while.  If it doesn't affect anything performance-wise, you could always draw on a background thread.  I don't know how safe CIImage or UIImage are, but Core Graphics is generally threadsafe.

Comment: [context release] crash my app.

Comment: Hmm... Run instruments with leaks

Comment: Convenience constructors like -[NSString stringWithFormat:] etc. return their result value autoreleased, so you do _not_ have to release the CIContext. The crash is not surprising, because you're overreleasing the object. The console output should contain something like `*** -[CIContext release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14ce6aa0`

Comment: @TobiasKlüpfel My bad.  I think I meant to say he was under-releasing the CIImage, which makes far more sense in retrospect.